# Calculating a loop size in bash script gives back different output than writing the size hard coded

Tags: bash, loops

When I run the following program

```
for i in {0..18}; do 
        for j in {0..18}; do
                for k in {0..18}; do
                        echo $i $j $k   
                done
        done
done
```

I get the disired output like

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 0 2
```

and so on

However when I calculate the loop size like this:

```
steps=$((360/20))


echo $steps
for i in {0..$steps}; do 
        for j in {0..$steps}; do
                for k in {0..$steps}; do
                        echo $i $j $k   
                done
        done
done
```

I get the following output:

```
{0..18} {0..18} {0..18}
```

How can I get the desired output like in the first script? What's my error here?

Comment: Simple fact.. range expansion happens before parameter expansion, the loop will never work!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so basically, the loop itself does not expand over the parameters, cause the range gets expanded before the parameter gets expanded ?

Comment: The title may not seem like an exact duplicate, but excluding the answers involving `eval`, ones with for loop with `for ((..))` is the right way to do!

Comment: Yes you got it right!